# Regex crash at initialization on Windows

Tags: c++, regex, windows

I'm trying to use a .ini file as a configuration file, and to do so I'm using regex.

What I currently do is a getline of my file and for each line I get, I'm trying to determine if it is corresponding to a scope or not with the following regex : "`^\[[a-zA-Z0-9]+\]$`"

This regex works well according to https://regex101.com/ and Unix, but crash on my windows application (yes I try to make this app cross-platform)

So I'm wondering what is going wrong here, and why does this regex make the program crash, and how to solve this problem...

Thank everybody !

Comment: Are you sure about the outer [] there?

Comment: @Joey is right. I guess you're after `"^\\[[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\]$"`.

Answer (score 0):

You've missed the quoting of the outer brackets. Try

```
^\[[a-zA-Z0-9]+\]$
```

or simpler

```
^\[\w+\]$
```

And don't forget to escape the `\`s in the c++ string ;)

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hs89zB/1).

Comment: Any comment on this, void?